# Creating and Using Global Object in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an authentication object that I instantiate when the life cycle of my app begins and I need to access this object from multiple places.

In my previous bare React Native project, I simply declared my object as `global.auth` in the `index.js` file and was able to access it anywhere in my app by referencing it as `global.auth`.

I just started a new managed Expo project with the latest SDK and when I used this approach, I get the following error message:

> Your project is accessing the following APIs from a deprecated global
> rather than a module import: Constants (expo-constants).

How do I instantiate and use a global object in my Expo app?

Here's what I do in my bare React Native project. This is the `index.js` file:

```
import Auth from 'my-auth-package';

global.auth = new Auth();
```

Then in any component or util file, I can simply access it with `global.auth`.

Expo doesn't seem to like this. What's the correct way of handling this in a new Expo project -- with SDK 40?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for context

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html